# Regelhaft oder regelmäßig

Tags: german-to-english

Please I would like to know if these 2 words are interchangeable

Comment: I believe in a context where you describe how often, or regularily, you do something, you cannot use regelhaft.

Comment: Welcome! As for all questions of this kind, did you check a dictionary? And if so, what did you find?

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not all generally interchangeable. The adjectives

- regelhaft
- regelkonform
- regelgemäß

mean that something is *regulated, follows or complies with the rules*. Examples:

> Wir unterscheiden chaotische und regelhafte Systeme.
>
> (We distinguish between chaotic and regulated systems.)
>
> Die Wahl war regelkonform.
>
> (The election was in accordance to the rules.)

Although in certain contexts also the adjective

- regelmäßig

may be used like that, it is more frequently used when something *happens regularly or periodically* that is again and again. But none of the first three adjectives would fit with this meaning. Example:

> Sie können der Krankheit durch regelmäßige Untersuchungen vorbeugen.
>
> (You can prevent the disease by periodic examinations.)

Comment: Thank u very much